# Hovering over image make other disappear

Tags: html, jquery, mouseover

Have created a feature when hovering over an image in a gallery, all other images are dimmed and a movie clip is played. [Live page](http://danborjesson.com/start-2/)

Looking for help with three things:

1. I want the caption of the image to retain its opacity when hovering over the image. Have tried with the following on hover but nothing happens:

```
$(this).parent().siblings(".media-title").css('opacity', '1');
```

2. What would be the easiest way to start the same function at 'mouseover' but that it only lasts for 3 seconds and then removing the film and giving the other images full opacity?
3. If you hover over the images quickly, some images retain their low opacity, can this be prevented?

My setup:

```
<div class="db-gallery">
                            
<div class="db-thumb">
<img class="gallery-img" src="url"/>
<video class="clip" style="display:none;">
<source src="url" autoplay="false" muted="muted" type="video/mp4" /></video>
</div>

<div class="media-title">                               
<p class="caption">Title</p>
</div>

</div>
```

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.db-thumb', function() {
    $(this).find(".clip").css("display", "block");
    $(this).find(".clip").get(0).muted = true;
    $(this).find(".clip").get(0).load();
    $(this).find(".clip").get(0).play();    
    $(".gallery-img:not(:hover)").css('opacity', '0.1');
    $(".media-title:not(:hover)").css('opacity', '0.1'); 
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.db-thumb', function() {
    $(this).find(".clip").get(0).currentTime = 0;
    $(this).find(".clip").get(0).pause();
    $(this).find(".clip").css("display","none");
    $(".gallery-img:not(:hover)").css('opacity', '1');
    $(".media-title:not(:hover)").css('opacity', '1');
});
```

Comment: an ID is supposed to be unique. there are 13 (!!!) `#db-thumb` in your code, wtf. use css for all that hover opacity stuff, not JS.

Comment: @zangab my bad. changed all now. And found: .db-thumb:hover ~ .media-title {
 opacity: 1 !important; } working for the caption. Thanks